# delayed_job passing instance methods & variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process, delayed-job

I have a problem with getting application data from outside of self.method.

To useModel.delay.method, the method has to be a class one.

I really like that, it does all I need (like saving input parameters when calling method), but what I need to do is get variables from outside of method.

For example:
User clicks button and starts the timer.

```
QuizzesController.delay(run_at: @quiz.time_limit.minutes.from_now).form_timeout(session[:user_id],session[:test_password])
```

Method form_timeout looks like this:

```
def self.form_timeout(id, test_password)
  if test_password == session[:test_password]
    Score.create(user_id: id, name: test_password, points: -1) 
    session.delete(:test_password)
  end
end
```

When I try to do that, I get an error "undefined method session" which means that I cannot reach that data when using self.method.

Any idea how to bypass that and let `session[:test_password]` (session has to pass most up-to-date information, because I compare `session[:test_password]` from time when timer has started (old one) and from time when it ends(new one)) like i did in self.method?

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea how to bypass that and let `session[:test_password]`...

Nope, no way of doing that. `session` is not a simple instance methods. It gets data from cookies (by default). And cookies are inaccessible in a background worker context.

Rule of thumb for background workers is: delayed method must receive all data it needs in its parameters.

Comment: Can I access other instance methods? I could make class method that pass parameters (after timer gets to 0) to instant method and calls it. Does that make sense?

Comment: methods on which instance of what class, may I ask?

Comment: Call instance method inside class method. I've read some things and seems like I can't do that.

Comment: But, now that I think of. Can I check in class method, if there is some particular record in database meeting some requirments, like date of creation within 15 minutes?

Comment: @Kappa: yep, that you can do.